# Creating a link that opens a popup on a Google Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have this code that transform all the words "test" on a page into links to Google.
Is there any way to make clicking on these links open my popup.html instead?

```
searchPattern = new RegExp ("(test)", "gi");
var pageText = document.body.innerHTML;
document.body.innerHTML = pageText.replace(searchPattern, "<a href='https://www.google.com/#q=$1'>$1</a>");
```

Edit: Ok so I have this function now instead of the link, still not sure how to call the extension's popup.html through the page's HTML code:

```
document.body.innerHTML = pageText.replace(searchPattern, "<a class='popup'>$1$2$3</a>" +
        "<script>$('popup').click(function(e) {e.preventDefault();" +
        "});</script>");
```

Comment: on the links use jquery click function, prevent the default operation and do what you have to. $('a').click(function(e){e.preventDefault(); TODO });

Comment: @Skalár Wag Thanks a lot, still not sure how to call the extension's popup.html via the page's HTML though

Comment: Oh, sorry. You cannot open the extension's popup programmatically. You  can show or modify pageaction icon -- which is not the same.